# How can I check if a certain file type exists in a directory?

Tags: ruby

I'm building an application and I must be able to check if a specific extension (example: .exe, .html, .rb - that kind of stuff) exists in a certain directory.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yeah, I tried something similar to the answer from Ursus which but I didn't add the "any?" part.

Comment: You should always add your efforts to the question. Like, *so far I've tried:*.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
Dir['some_dir/*.exe'].any?
```

With subfolders

```
Dir['some_dir/**/*.exe'].any?
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the names of the directory, `dir_name`, and the filename extension, `ext`  (including the period, unless `ext` is empty), you could write:

```
Dir.foreach(dir_name).any? { |fname| File.extname(fname) == ext }
```

See [Dir#foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html#method-c-foreach), [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) and [File::extname](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-extname).